# How to make an html5 video with 100% width vertically center align

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, video

I want to show a responsive html5 video with 100% width and auto height in such a way that the space above it is equal to the space below it on all screens and devices. This is my code.

```css
body,
video {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<video controls>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>
```

I tried to achieve this with different ideas like setting margins but they all failed. I am open to javascript/jquery/plugins if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by centering with flexbox CSS like so:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

video {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video controls>
<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: wow this is the fastest i have ever gotten a correct helpful answer on stackoverflow thanks

Comment: Elegant and clever solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [at how bootstrap achieves this.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/7085988f06954413ac2c72fed23e30a38ecd6dff/scss/utilities/_embed.scss) They use a wrapping div to control the dimensions and set the video to be absolutely positioned with 100% width and height. It's a bit more flexible than Jon's solution, although that does do what you want.